# Android Stub Problems

Tags: java, android, stub

A while ago I followed some tutorials but failed at lines of code like this one :

```
public class RemoteControlDisplay extends IRemoteControlDisplay.Stub {
```

It does not find `IRemoteControlDisplay.Stub`. Eclipse always had problems with `Stub`s.

I'm currently following [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=44513199) tutorial but it just won't work. The errors say `IRemoteControlDisplay cannot be resolved to be a type`. Why can I never extend these `.Stub`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/

The above link explains how to enable `com.android.internal` and `@hide` areas of the API. This should allow the ADT plugin for Eclipse to find and *use* the stub.

Bear in mind that this is in no way guaranteed to work. The hidden areas of the ADT are often changed when they are updated.

Comment: But IRemoteControlDisplay isn't within com.android.internal.

Comment: It is partially hidden: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/media/IRemoteControlDisplay.java

Comment: @JamesB There's also something to do with weak linkage, and some clever memory resource management at play here. AFAIK, I'm not sure how thats implemented. Despite the stub not being in `.internal` itself, there is some sort of handler that is either hidden or locked up there.

Comment: @Wolfish I read the article several times but I couldn't find a way to enable it for me :( It just told me why they are hidden...

Comment: @Wolfish well I thought I should change the access rules now from that library but whenver I set it from Frobidden to Accessible as shown in the last picture from your link, it is set to forbidden again when I reopen the java build path..

Comment: @Davlog that's... confusing. Did you follow these three pages? - https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-2-hacking-around/ , https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-3-custom-android-platform/ and https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-4-customizing-adt/

Comment: @Wolfish ah nevermind. Eclipse just had to restart. Works now, thanks :)